# Lua fork concurrent processes

Tags: lua, fork

I want to execute background processes concurrently from a lua script

like :

```
a = io.popen("deploy.exp" .. ip1):read("*a")
b = io.popen("deploy.exp" .. ip2):read("*a")
```

where a,b are continually running processes. When i do this as above, b will only run when a is finished. And the deploy.exp script is an expect script which used to ssh few servers, and execute some commands. Then I need to fetch some text from a and b. Any idea on this? I tryed with the ExtensionProposal API. When I tried that I get one error messages that say: "*** glibc detected**  free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08aa2300 ** abort".

The part code is

```
for k,v in pairs(single) do
command =  k .. " 1 " ..  table.concat(v, " ")
local out = io.pipe()
local pro = assert(os.spawn("./spaw.exp " .. command,{
      stdout = out,  
}))
if not proc then error("Failed to aprogrinate! "..tostring(err)) end
print(string.rep("#", 50))
local exitcode = proc:wait()
end
```

Has anybody any experience (or advice / where we should look) with this? or give me a sample? Thanks

BTW: I tried the luaposix, but I can't find any sample by posix.fork(). Does anyone could     share one? TKS

Comment: "*I can't find any sample by posix.fork().*" Can you not simply try it and see what happens?

Comment: But i really don't know it usage. OK, by going through a lot of aggravation searching stuff out on the web and reading code, but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

posix.fork() is part of the [luaposix library](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix), which can be installed via [luarocks](http://luarocks.org/). It works in much the same way as [fork(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork); it creates an copy of the parent process, and both of them will execute everything after the call to fork().  The return value of fork() is 0 in the child process, otherwise it's the PID of the child that was just spawned.  Here's a contrived example:

```
local posix = require "posix"
local pid = posix.fork()

if pid == 0 then 
  -- this is the child process
  print(posix.getpid('pid') .. ": child process")

else 
  -- this is the parent process
  print(posix.getpid('pid') .. ": parent process")

  -- wait for the child process to finish
  posix.wait(pid) 

end

-- both processes get here
print(posix.getpid('pid') .. ": quitting")
```

This should output something like the following:

```
$ lua fork.lua 
27219: parent process
27220: child process
27220: quitting
27219: quitting
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [Lua Lanes](http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/askok/bin/lanes/) (or from [here](https://github.com/LuaLanes/lanes)), which is a portable threading library for Lua.

Comment: [here](http://www.luteus.biz/Download/LoriotPro_Doc/LUA/LUA_For_Windows/lanes/comparison.html)'s a comparison of other concurrency libraries for Lua

Comment: and [here](http://pastebin.com/934dhTni)'s an example for lanes (works with Lanes in LuaForWindows)